# Criterion for a locally factorial domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain. Recall that $R$ is said to be *locally factorial* if $R_\mathfrak p$ is factorial for all prime ideals $\mathfrak p\subset R$. How do I show that $R$ is locally factorial iff every height one prime ideal in $R$ is a locally free $R$-module of rank one?

**Update:** Let me make this question more specific.

I think I figured out how to prove that 'locally factorial' implies 'locally principal'. So the question is how to prove the converse. What is written below is inspired by Proposition 19.22 from [here](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).

Suppose every height one prime in $R$ is a locally free $R$-module of rank one. Let $Q$ be such a prime. The ring $(R_Q, QR_Q)$ is then a Noetherian local domain. Furthermore, because $Q$ is a locally free module of rank $1$, the maximal ideal $QR_Q=Q_Q$ is principal. There is a theorem ([Theorem 17.19](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf)) saying that for a one-dimensional Noetherian local domain with maximal ideal $m$, the condition that $m$ be principal is equivalent to the condition that $R$ be a PID. I guess I have to use this result. But what I don't understand is why $R_Q$ has Krull dimension one. Moreover, even if one applies this theorem, one only proves that $R_Q$ is a UFD for *height one* primes. But how to establish this for all primes?

Comment: You’ve checked this for the simplest case, of polynomial rings over a field?

Comment: If the current version of the statement is false and becomes true on substituting "height" for "co-height", then I mean "height".

Comment: Instead of Theorem 17.19 I'd use Theorem 15.1 (Kaplansky's criterion for UFDs).

Answer (score 1):

The following two results are taken from section 3 of [CDZ]. They characterize
locally factorial domains generally.

Lemma 3.1 An integral domain $D$ is factorial if and only if every
minimal prime of a nonzero principal ideal of $D$ is principal.

Proof. Indeed, as a principal ideal is invertible and hence $t$-invertible,
by Kang's result, $D$ is Krull and as in a Krull domain the minimal primes
of nonzero principal ideals are of height one we have a Krull domain whose
height one primes are all principal which is a UFD. The converse is obvious.

Using Lemma 3.1. we can state the following characterization of locally
factorial domains.

Proposition 3.2. An integral domain $D$ is locally factorial if and only if
every minimal prime of a nonzero principal ideal is is locally principal.

Proof. Let $D$ be locally factorial and let $P$ be a minimal prime of a
nonzero principal ideal of $D$. Then for any maximal ideal $M,$ $PD_{M}$ is
a minimal prime of a nonzero principal ideal of $D_{M}$ and hence principal
if $P\subseteq M,$ otherwise $PD_{M}=D_{M}.$ Thus every minimal prime of a
principal ideal is locally principal. Conversely suppose that every minimal
prime of every principal ideal is locally principal and let $M$ \ be a
maximal ideal of $D.$ Now let $\mathcal{P}$ be a minimal prime of a
principal ideal of $D_{M}.$ Then it is easy to see that $\mathcal{P}$ $%
=PD_{M}$ where $P$ is a minimal prime of a principal ideal. But then $PD_{M}$
is principal and so is $\mathcal{P}.$ As $\mathcal{P}$ is arbitrary we
conclude, by Lemma 3.1$,$ that $D_{M}$ is factorial.

The Noetheran locally factorial domain is a special case and in a Noetheran
domain every minimal prime of a principal ideal is of height one and of
course in any integral domain a height one prime ideal is a minimal prime of
a principal ideal.

[CDZ] Gyu Whan Chang, Tiberiu Dumitrescu and Muhammad
Zafrullah, Locally GCD domains and the ring $D+XD_{S}[X],$ 42(2016), 263-284.

Note. User 26857 commented (and then deleted the comment) in another context that Lemma 3.1 follows from Kaplansky's theorem on UFD's. A lot of results do, but what we get from "misusing" Kaplansky is a general criterion. User 26857 didn't. To see that the readers may look up section 3 of [CDZ].

Comment: I may not have addressed this part adequately "But what I don't understand is why RQ has Krull dimension one. Moreover, even if one applies this theorem, one only proves that RQ is a UFD for height one primes. But how to establish this for all primes?"